# Move title bar to bottom of window

Tags: windows, windows-xp, window, whiteboard

Often when using a SmartBoard (interactive whiteboard), people can't reach the window controls at the top of the board, i.e. to minimize, close, maximise/restore, or move the window.

So I was wondering if it is possible to move the titlebar to the bottom of the window, in windows XP? Obviously 3rd party software will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently possible with Windows XP.

I would recommend pressing the **Right-Click** button on the **pen tray**, and then pressing the interactive whiteboard with your finger on the task bar to **right click** and click **minimize or close** on the windows you wish to close.